# Setting up my ATL COM callback functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, idl

A follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005771/callbacks-in-com-objects), I have the following `CerberusNative.idl` file (this is an ATL project written in Visual C++ which exposes a COM object):

```
[
    object,
    uuid(AECE8D0C-F902-4311-A374-ED3A0EBB6B49),
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICallbacks : IUnknown
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT UserExit([in] int errorCode, [in] BSTR errorMessage);
    [id(2)] HRESULT UserAttemptingReconnection();
    [id(3)] HRESULT UserReconnected();
};

[
    object,
    uuid(B98A7D3F-651A-49BE-9744-2B1D8C896E9E),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICerberusSession : IDispatch {
    ...
    [id(5)] HRESULT SetCallbacks([in] ICallbacks* callbacks);
};
```

I am attempting to create an interface for setting up callback methods which route from the COM object back to an implementation of said methods from the caller.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
HRESULT prolonguedDisconnection(int code, BSTR *message) {
    std::wcout << code << ": " << message << std::endl;
}
HRESULT reconnecting() {
    std::wcout << "Reconnecting." << std::endl;
}
HRESULT reconnected() {
    std::wcout << "Reconnected." << std::endl;
}
...
CoInitialize(NULL);
CerberusNativeLib::ICallbacksPtr callbacks;
callbacks.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CerberusNativeLib::ICallbacks));
callbacks->UserExit = prolonguedDisconnection;
callbacks->UserAttemptingReconnection = reconnecting;
callbacks->UserReconnected = reconnected;
CerberusNativeLib::ICerberusSessionPtr session;
session.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CerberusNativeLib::CerberusSession));
session->SetCallbacks(callbacks);
```

However, I am not sure how to properly set up the callback methods. Any ideas on how to do this? I get this compiler error on lines such as `callbacks->UserExit = prolonguedDisconnection;`:

> Error C2659   '=': function as left operand

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I needed simply to implement the interface in a separate class:

```
class Callbacks : public CerberusNativeLib::ICallbacks {

#define MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(type,name,l,w1,w2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) \
        const type name = {l,w1,w2,{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8}}

MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(IID, IID_ICallbacks, 0xAECE8D0C, 0xF902, 0x4311, 0xA3, 0x74, 0xED, 0x3A, 0x0E, 0xBB, 0x6B, 0x49);

public:

    HRESULT(*user_exit) (int, BSTR) = NULL;
    HRESULT(*user_attempting_reconnection) () = NULL;
    HRESULT(*user_reconnected) () = NULL;

    Callbacks::Callbacks(HRESULT(*disconnected)(int, BSTR), HRESULT(*reconnecting)(), HRESULT(*reconnected)()) : m_cRef(0) {
        user_exit = disconnected;
        user_attempting_reconnection = reconnecting;
        user_reconnected = reconnected;
    }

    HRESULT __stdcall UserExit(int ErrorCode, BSTR ErrorMessage) {
        return user_exit(ErrorCode, ErrorMessage);
    }
    HRESULT __stdcall UserAttemptingReconnection() {
        return user_attempting_reconnection();
    }
    HRESULT __stdcall UserReconnected() {
        return user_reconnected();
    }
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, _COM_Outptr_ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject) {
        if (!ppvObject)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        *ppvObject = NULL;
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_ICallbacks)
        {
            *ppvObject = (LPVOID)this;
            AddRef();
            return NOERROR;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() {
        InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
        return m_cRef;
    }
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() {
        ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
        if (0 == m_cRef)
            delete this;
        return ulRefCount;
    }

private:
    ULONG m_cRef;
};
```

Then, to use it:

```
HRESULT result = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (result != S_OK)
{
    std::wcout << "Failed to initialize the COM library on the current thread or to identify the concurrency model as single-thread apartment (STA)." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << result << ": " << _com_error(result).ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Press the enter key to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
Callbacks *callbacks = new Callbacks(&prolonguedDisconnection, &reconnecting, &reconnected);
CerberusNativeLib::ICerberusSessionPtr session;
result = session.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CerberusNativeLib::CerberusSession));
if (result != S_OK)
{
    std::wcout << "Failed to create a new Cerberus session." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << result << ": " << _com_error(result).ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Press the enter key to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
result = session->SetCallbacks(callbacks);
if (result != S_OK)
{
    std::wcout << "Failed to set Cerberus session callbacks." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << result << ": " << _com_error(result).ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Press the enter key to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to encounter a world of problems with that implementation. Your AddRef, Release and QueryInterface methods should work correctly, or else you'll leak, crash, be unable to use any of the language-level tools provided for COM (e.g. CComPtr or _com_ptr_t), and write code that doesn't adhere to COM fundamental principles.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Updated for completion, but probably useless because of the method of use.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `ICallbacks` as an interface and the object that implements `ICerberusSession` accepts a `ICallbacks` pointer so that it could invoke calls back on certain events. This is a good design and works well. However, it usually assumes that your code (last code snippet at the bottom) instantiates session object via `CreateInstance` as you do, and the other interface with callback methods is implemented on your side.

Your code implements a COM object, which in turn implements `ICallbacks`. You create an instance of such COM object (esp. without `CoCreateInstace` - it's typically client code on your side) and you pass `ICallbacks` interface as an argument in `SetCallbacks` call. Note that there is no assignment involved. Session object is expected to do a call, e.g. `ICallbacks::UserExit` on supplied pointer and this is how your code receives control through the callback interface - your client side code implementation of `ICallbacks` has its `UserExit` method called.

Comment: I am not sure how to instantiate `ICallbacks` and set up the functions on it without `CoCreateInstance`. Seeing some example code here would be very helpful to me.

Comment: You defined an interface. There is no implementation yet - you need to create it. `CoCreateInstance` creates an instance of already existing implementation by identifier. Here you typically need to implement a COM object in code, and this object would implement the callback interface in question. A very rough example is given [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562479): `CFakeCallback` class implements a [callback] interface `ISampleGrabberCB`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.

Comment: Note that while `CFakeCallback` above demonstrates the idea, you are doing ATL and your implementation should rather leverage regular ATL classes for COM base, like `CComObjectRootEx` and friends. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1506486/868014) mentions class `CBlah` which gives a better idea for elements of ATL class implementation.